# how to write text/label on a line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

i have pinescript code that show Tokyo, London, And NY open with vertical line, what i wanted is to add text/label on the each session line

```
//@version=5
indicator('Timegap', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_bars_back=4999)

weekday = (dayofweek.saturday and dayofweek.sunday)

t1 = timestamp("GMT+7", year, month, hour, 07, 00, 00)
t2 = timestamp("GMT+7", year, month, hour, 14, 00, 00)
t3 = timestamp("GMT+7", year, month, hour, 20, 00, 00)
t4 = timestamp("GMT+7", year, month, hour, 00, 00, 00)

line.new(t1, low, t1, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.rgb(24, 21, 240), line.style_solid, 1)
line.new(t2, low, t2, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.rgb(255, 235, 59), line.style_solid, 1)
line.new(t3, low, t3, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.rgb(255, 82, 82), line.style_solid, 1)
line.new(t4, low, t4, high, xloc.bar_time, extend.both, color.rgb(54, 58, 69), line.style_solid, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this after each line you create :

```
label.new(t1,close,"Session", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar, textcolor=color.white)
```

Which will draw :
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but Can you move the label to the bottom? Also showing the text vertically

Comment: @RiyadlMufidIsfihanni to change the position of the label you must change yloc=yloc.abovebar in the code (look in the manual for all the possibilities). I don't think you can write vertically in tradingview